# Setup an email notification when consumer: Connection to broker lost in celery

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, worker

I want to implement an email system which will send an email whenever my celery worker lost connection with my Redis server.

Whenever it lost connection it gives warning:
`[2023-03-02 21:33:48,272: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...`

And starts reconnecting with the server
`[2023-03-02 21:33:48,286: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://127.0.0.1:6379//: Error 61 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.. Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)`

I am using django 3.2.8 and celery 5.2.7.

I went through the whole celery docs and source code I get to know there is a method `on_connection_error_after_connected` in the `celery.worker.consumer.consumer` which get's triggered when it lost connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution. I setup a different log and which logs the celery and also checks for any warn or error message similar to the connection lost. The code for that is here:

```
# Project/celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
import logging
import celery
import logstash
from django.conf import settings
from utils.email_alert import send_shutting_down_email
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','Project.settings')
app = Celery('Project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

class LogstashEmailHandler(logging.handlers.SocketHandler):
    def __init__(self, host, port, sender):
        super().__init__(host, port)
        self.sender = sender
    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            # Send the log message to Logstash
            logging.handlers.SocketHandler.emit(self, record)
        except Exception:
            self.handleError(record)
        if 'consumer: Connection to broker lost.' in record.message:
            send_shutting_down_email(record.message, 'Connection to broker lost.')
            os.system("ps auxww | grep celery | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -HUP && celery -A project worker -l info")
        elif 'Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)' in record.message:
            send_shutting_down_email(record.message, 'Trying to connect to broker url.')



from celery.signals import after_setup_task_logger
from celery.signals import after_setup_logger

@after_setup_task_logger.connect
@after_setup_logger.connect
def initialize_logstash(logger=None,loglevel=logging.INFO, **kwargs):
    handler = logstash.TCPLogstashHandler(settings.LOGSTASH_HOST, 5960,tags=['celery-' + settings.ENV_NAME],message_type='celery',version=1)
    handler.setLevel(loglevel)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    customhandler = LogstashEmailHandler(host= settings.LOGSTASH_HOST, port= 5960, sender = kwargs.get('sender'))
    logger.addHandler(customhandler)
    return logger
```

Here `send_shutting_down_email` is the function which takes the message and subject as argument and sends it.

```
# send_shutting_down_email
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from project.settings import ENV_NAME

def send_shutting_down_email(msg, sub):
    subject = f'Project Celery {ENV_NAME} message: {sub}'
    html_content = render_to_string('mails/celery.html', {'msg':msg,'env':ENV_NAME})
    text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
    mail_to_send = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject,
        text_content,
        "alert@dummyemail.com",
        ['email@dummyemail.com']
    )
    mail_to_send.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    mail_to_send.send()
```

I believe there is a better way of doing this. If any then please let me know!